# Which of the following strings will be matched by the regex below?

Tags: php, regex

I just take an exam with 15 questions. I answered smoothly to 11 of the 15 question, but now i have to answer 4 question about regex (in not my strong point).

So, first question:

```
Which of the following strings will be matched by the regex below?
$regex = '/^\d+[a-c]{2,4}$/';

a. ab12cd

b. 1234a

c. 12ab34

d. 1234abc

e. 1a2b3c
```

Second question:

```
Which of the following strings will be matched by the regex below? (choose two)
/^\d([a-i]|\d)\w+$/

a. 3x3

b. 12ab

c. 3hree

d. ab12cd

e. 1two3
```

Third question

```
Which of the following are true regarding the regex below? (choose two)
/^\d([a-z]+)\d{2}/

a. the reggex doesn't contain any subpatterns

b. subpattern number 1 is ([a-z]+)

c. subpattern number 0 is ([a-z]+)

d. the regex contains two subpatterns: ([a-z]+) and {2}

e. the regex contains one subpattern: ([a-z]+)
```

And the last one:

```
Which of the following are NOT true about the code section below? (choose two)
$regex = '/\d.[13]/';

a. the [13] character class will match the number 13

b. the [13] character class will match either 1 and 3

c. the regex matches strings that have a lenght of 13 characters

d. \d is a character class that indicates a digit

e. the regexx matches strings that contain only digits
```

Is the final exam and i have one last chance. Please help me!

Comment: Ans: https://regex101.com

Comment: Try all your regexs to https://www.regex101.com/ as Raj Sir suggested.